# How do I serialize an object that has a list of objects as a parameter into query-string format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, serialization, query-string

I have an object which properties I need to serialize to query-string so I can send the request to the server, I found a solution that solves my problem partially, it serializes everything but the List of objects which is a parameter of my class, thus the problem.
Here's the code that serializes everything but the List of objects.

```
 public static string ToQueryString(this object request, string separator = ",")
        {
            if (request == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

            // Get all properties on the object
            var properties = request.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.CanRead)
                .Where(x => x.GetValue(request, null) != null)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(request, null));

            // Get names for all IEnumerable properties (excl. string)
            var propertyNames = properties
                .Where(x => !(x.Value is string) && x.Value is IEnumerable)
                .Select(x => x.Key)
                .ToList();

            // Concat all IEnumerable properties into a comma separated string
            foreach (var key in propertyNames)
            {
                var valueType = properties[key].GetType();
                var valueElemType = valueType.IsGenericType
                                        ? valueType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                                        : valueType.GetElementType();
                if (valueElemType.IsPrimitive || valueElemType == typeof(string))
                {
                    var enumerable = properties[key] as IEnumerable;
                    properties[key] = string.Join(separator, enumerable.Cast<object>());
                }
            }

            // Concat all key/value pairs into a string separated by ampersand
            return string.Join("&", properties
                .Select(x => string.Concat(
                    Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Key), "=",
                    Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Value.ToString()))));
        }
```

Here is the class example that I would need to serialize:

```
public class Criteria
    {
        public int? TestInt { get; set; }
        public List<int> ListaInt { get; set; }
        public List<DokumentAttributeSearchCriteria> DokumentCriterias { get; set; }
        public string TestString { get; set; }
        public DokumentAttributeSearchCriteria DokumentCriteria { get; set; }
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to expand this function so it will also work for List of object parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Newtonsoft.Json and HTTP POST (with JSON content-body) to send nested objects such as this because there is no standard way to represent lists of objects using query-string parameters

If GET is your only option, you could try something like this:

```
Uri.EscapeDataString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(criteria))
```

Converting it back to an object at the other end would be the reverse of this

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Uri.UnescapeDataString(queryString))
```